# Style CSS in JS React with Switch Statement?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, object

**Question:**

Is there a way to use react and CSS to set an individual component's background-color depending on three cases?

**Example:**

value = a - b;

switch(value)

case 1: value > 0 //Set the background "green".

case 2: value < 0 //Set the background "red".

case 3: value === 0 //Set the background "yellow".

I'm not looking for a ternary, because that's either 1 or 0, I'm looking for something I couldn't find in other React Stack Overflow Questions.

**Example code:**

```js
const App = () => {
  const array = [{
      count: 2,
      stock: 2
    },
    {
      count: 30,
      stock: 20
    },
    {
      count: 20,
      stock: 30
    }
  ];

  const differences = array.map((items) => {
    return <p > {
      items.stock - items.count
    } < /p>;
  });
  return <div > {
    differences
  } < /div>;
};
export default App;
```

I would like the first object

to be green,

the second object to be blue/yellow

and the third object to be red.

**100% dynamic.**

**Any info would help, Thanks!**

Comment: You can use a function name with className in react. Like this. className={getClass(items)}

Comment: @Vimal Patel, Thanks, Man! That worked, I simply called an ES6 function with 3 if statements inside. Then returned a className for each statement. Lastly, I passed the function name into the className object.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at styled-components. Very dynamic. You can make your style depend on props by passing them down to style. CSS-in-JS

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,  Vimal Patel!

**STEPS:**

1. Create function inside map function.
2. Assign your classes to the if statements return values.
3. Pass your functionName() to the className={functionName()} object.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
import "./Style.css"

const App = () => {
    const array = [{
        count: 2,
        stock: 2
      },
      {
        count: 30,
        stock: 20
      },
      {
        count: 20,
        stock: 30
      }
    ];

    const differences = array.map((items) => {
        const classnameFunc = () => {
          const discrepency = items.stock - items.count;
          if (discrepency === 0) {
            return "blueClass"
          } else if (discrepency > 0) {
            return "greenClass";
          } else {
            return "yellowClass";
          }

          return <p className = {
            classnameFunc()
          } > {
            items.stock - items.count
          } < /p>;
        });
      return <div > {
        differences
      } < /div>;
    };
    export default App;
```

```css
.greenClass {
  background-color: green;
}

.redClass {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellowClass {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: You can improve your code. Check this out. https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-glitter-kssw2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Even better! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I actually used this very switch statement in my react component*

```
 const getDescriptionClassName = () => { 


  switch(true) {
    case(formats.includes('bold')): return "desc-textarea bold-text italic-text"
    // case(2): return "class2"
    default: return "desc-textarea"
  }
   
}

<textarea className={getDescriptionClassName()} rows={10} cols={50} placeholder="W

rite a description..."/>
```